# How scroll to a specific position on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, scroll, autoscroll

When I clicked on the link "Add comment". Appears comment form, with help of Ajax. I need scroll to it, please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice smooth animation with jQuery:

```
$("html, body").animate({scrollTop : $("form#comment").offset().top}, "fast");
```

Answer (score 4):

you can scroll to a specific point by id or by any jquery selecter.
`check this :` http://jsfiddle.net/UPRkm/55/

Answer (score 1):

Find the elements x, y position and use `window.scrollTo(x, y)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it helps: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo

Answer (score 0):

```
<a name="ScrollTo"></a>

<a href="#ScrollTo">Comments Link</a>
```